# Should I use softmax as output when using cross entropy loss in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, softmax

I have a problem with classifying fully connected deep neural net with 2 hidden layers for **MNIST dataset in pytorch**.

I want to use **tanh** as activations in both hidden layers, but in the end, I should use **softmax**.

For the loss, I am choosing `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` in PyTOrch, which (as I have found out) does not want to take one-hot encoded labels as true labels, but takes LongTensor of classes instead.

My model is `nn.Sequential()` and when I am using softmax in the end, it gives me worse results in terms of accuracy on testing data. Why?

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

inputs, n_hidden0, n_hidden1, out = 784, 128, 64, 10
n_epochs = 500
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(inputs, n_hidden0, bias=True), 
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(n_hidden0, n_hidden1, bias=True),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(n_hidden1, out, bias=True),
    nn.Softmax()  # SHOULD THIS BE THERE?
)
                 
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.5)

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, Y_train)
    print('epoch: ', epoch+1,' loss: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thanks for this question. Here is an example of a classification NN that has ONLY nn.CrossEntropyLoss() without softmax https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html#

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As stated in the [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) doc:

> This criterion combines [`nn.LogSoftmax()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LogSoftmax.html) and [`nn.NLLLoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) in one single class.

Therefore, you should **not** use softmax before.

Comment: fixed the url
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss Note that this case is equivalent to the combination of LogSoftmax and NLLLoss.

Comment: But is it necessary to add softmax to the output of model in eval mode?

Comment: @user1744585 it depends on your needs... if the expected output is a probability, then yes, otherwise you can use the logits directly