# PyTorch errors - softmax not giving probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a custom neural network model using PyTorch for a classification task.
When I inspect the output probabilities, they don't sum up to 1. I've added a torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1) layer at the end of my model, which should normalize the output to probabilities, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```py
def custom_model(input_size, output_size):
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(input_size, 64),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(64, output_size),
        torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)  # Softmax layer for classification
    )
    return model


input_size = 10
output_size = 5


model = custom_model(input_size, output_size)


criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimiser = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)


input_data = torch.randn(32, input_size)
target = torch.randint(0, output_size, (32,))

output = model(input_data)

loss = criterion(output, target)


optimiser.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimiser.step()

print(f'Loss: {loss.item()}')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: To what value do they sum up?

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't add up to 1

Comment: Yes but that is not what I asked, please answer exactly what I asked.

Comment: it depends because of the torch.randint function

Comment: Ok, you did not answer, so I cannot really help you. In Stack Overflow get a sliver of attention from experts, do not waste it by ignoring what people are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use softmax as output when using cross entropy loss in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675345/should-i-use-softmax-as-output-when-using-cross-entropy-loss-in-pytorch)